# jquery toggle with buttons two images?

Tags: jquery, image, button, toggle

To toggle hide/show, i used this code;

```
togglebtn.click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('.togglecontainer').toggle(500, function(){
        var txt = $(that).html();
        $(that).html((txt == 'Show less') ? 'Show more' : 'Show less');
    });
});
togglebtn.trigger("click");
```

But it toggles text inside one button. I want two buttons, with two diffrent img src's
let's say images/show.png and images/hide.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you enclosing `txt == 'Show less'` in parentheses?

Comment: well i got this solution from another question, but now i'm adding the graphics and i'm stuck with this text, because i want images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this Tutorial - [jQuery Image Swap Using Click](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-using-click/) - This may be what you are trying to achieve. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what i want, but also the jQuery toggle function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure this is wat you mean but:
You could use the Id's of the buttons

```
togglebtn.click(function(){
            var btn = this;
        $('.togglecontainer').toggle(500, function(){
            var txt = $(btn).html();
            $(btn).html((txt == 'Show less') ? 'Show more' : 'Show less');
            $("#btn2_Id").html((txt == 'Show less') ? '<img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/hide.png"/>' : '<img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/show.png"/>');
        });
});
```

Comment: It is what i mean, i dont need the txt though just the images

Comment: One should not use the `<img>` tag for buttons. `<img>` is for images that are relevant to the content, like a photo or a diagram. Buttons' images should be done with CSS. Use classes.