# jQuery hiding / showing button text

Tags: jquery

I have a button with text and a "spinner image". Initially the "spinner image" is hidden while text is shown, i want to toggle between the spinner and text.

```
<button id="yu1" class="searchbtn" onclick="return false;">Search<img class="spinner" src="/images/ajax_loader.gif"></button>
```

Can we hide and show button text without updating the text as I don't want to hold on to the text value itself?

Comment: How did you get 1000 reputation and write such a very low quality question ? You didn't gave any code. How can we know what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry why do you think its a low quality question?

Comment: Because you don't give matter to work with. Fore example we have to guess a html structure, etc ... Show us your code, I think you should know how it works here

Comment: ok added the HTML structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705454/jquery-toggle-with-buttons-two-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the HTML, you may add a `<span>` around the text and then with JQuery, you toggle the text with :

```
$("#yu1 span").hide();
$("#yu1 img").show();
```

And the reverse methods.

If you can't add a span around the text you can still hide only the text with :

```
$("#yu1").css("font-size","0");
```

and show it with :

```
$("#yu1").css("font-size","inherit");
```

---

**Update**

Improving my answer, you can write just a few jquery :

```
$("#yu1").bind("click", function () {    
    $(this).toggleClass("click");
});
```

And a few CSS :

```
button img{
    display: none;
    width:10px; //the width in not mandatory here, it's because the image was very large in the jsfiddle
}

button.click img{
    display:inline;
}

button.click{
    font-size:0;
}
```

Live example :
http://jsfiddle.net/11knzmpn/1/

Comment: That works but want to make sure width of the button is not distorted.

Comment: guess i could just give a fixed width to the button. Thanks

Comment: yes or use jquery to measure the size at the beginning, something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/11knzmpn/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can set the button color to transparent

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/11knzmpn/)

```
$("#yu1").on("click", function () {
    $(this).css("color", "transparent");
    $(this).find("img").show();

    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "black");
        $(this).find("img").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: tried your fix putting color as hard coded value is not desirable.